# Postgresql - How to generate script for all objects along with dependency in one go

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, how to generate script of all objects along with dependencies.
The script is required to create all objects with dependencies maintained.

Tried using backup, but didnt work.

I want plain script to drop & create tables, view, procedure, functions along with dependencies.

Comment: "Tried using backup, but didnt work." - please elaborate. The pg_dump program is designed to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Most of dependencies between SQL objects are implicit and you cannot export them easily (you would need a custom query to `pg_depend` catalog table). I mean dependencies like:

- VIEWs depend on used tables and columns
- tables depend on schemas
- table columns depend on data types
- expression-based indexes depend on functions used in expressions
- etc etc.

Fortunately, you don't need it as this type of dependencies is auto-resolved by native utility [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

You can use `pg_dump` to generate a script which will restore all the objects in proper order, with dependencies maintained.

For example:

```
# backup in the fastest `dir` format:
pg_dump "host=srv dbname=myapp user=admin" -Fd -j5 -v -f myapp.bak

# convert to text:
pg_restore myapp.bak -f myapp-restore.sql

# restore to empty db in some other server:
psql "host=newsrv dbname=myapp user=admin" -f myapp-restore.sql -e |& tee myapp-restore.log
```

Comment: How to generate script of all objects  from one schema

Comment: @user21707082, read the docs at the link [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). Do the homework.